# Only get alphanumeric characters in capture group using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Input:

```
x.y={aaa b .c}
```

Note that the the content within `{}` are only an example, in reality it could be any value.

**Problem**: I would like to keep only the alphanumeric characters **within the `{}`**.

So it would be come:

```
x.y={aaabbc}
```

#### Trial 0

```sh
$ echo 'x.y={aaa b .c}' | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]\+//g'
xyaaabc
```

This is great, but I'd like to only modify the part within `{}`. So I thought this may need capture groups, hence I went ahead and tried these:

#### Trial 1

```sh
$ echo 'x.y={aaa b .c}' | sed -E 's/x.y=\{(.*)\}/x.y={\1}/'
x.y={aaa b .c}
```

Here I have captured the content I want to modify (`aaa b .c`) correctly, but I need a way to somehow do `s/[^[:alnum:]]\+//g` **only on `\1`**.

Instead, I tried capturing *all alphanumeric characters only (to `\1`)* like this:

#### Trial 2

```sh
$ echo 'x.y={aaa b .c}' | sed -E 's/x.y=\{([[:alnum:]]+)\}/x.y={\1}/'
x.y={aaa b .c}
```

Of course, it doesn't work because I'm only *expecting* alnum's and then immediately a `}` literal. I didn't tell it to ignore the non-alnum's. I.e, this part:

```
s/x.y=\{([[:alnum:]]+)\}/x.y={\1}/
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It literally matches: an open brace, some alnum's, and a closing brace  -- which is not what I want. I'd like it to **match everything, but only capture the alnum's**.

---

Example of input/output:

```
x.y={aaa b .c} blah
blah
x.y={1 2 3 def} blah
blah
```

to

```
x.y={aaabc} blah
blah
x.y={123def} blah
blah
```

---

I searched the web before finally giving up and posting the question but I didn't find anything helpful as I didn't see anyone with a similar problem as mine. Would appreciate some help this as I'd love to have a better understanding of variables in regex/sed, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following in `awk`. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/\{[^}]*}/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[^{}a-zA-Z]/,"",val)
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/\{[^}]*}/){                      ##using match function of awk to match from { to first occurrence of }
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)            ##Creating val which has sub string of matched regex in it.
  gsub(/[^{}a-zA-Z]/,"",val)               ##Globally substituting everything apart from { } and alphabets in val.
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) ##saving everything before match val and everything after match here.
}
1                                          ##Printing line if it doesn't meet `match` condition mentioned above.
'  Input_file                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***Generic solution:*** In case you have multiple occurrences of { and } then try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
{
  line=""
  while(match($0,/\{[^}]*}/)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/[^{}a-zA-Z]/,"",val)
    line=(line?line:"") (substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  if(RSTART+RLENGTH!=length($0)){
    $0=line $0
  }
  else{
    $0=line
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Apologies for not including examples where input has multiple records that needs to be changed. I've adapted your answer like this so it keeps numbers as well, but it doesn't seems to work since nothing is printed after the last matching record: `echo "x.y={aaa b .c}blah"\n"x.y={ddd 0 . eee f}blahblah"\nblah | awk -v RS='x.y={[^}]*}' 'RT{gsub(/[^{}a-zA-Z0-9]/,"",RT);printf $0 RT}'` <-- all the blah's should be kept in that example, ideally.

Comment: @hedy, could you please do update your question with sample of input and keep it in a file not in `echo`(its not clear if you have new lines in it or not so better keep it in a file format or so in your question), because its for variables, let me know once you edit, I will check it and edit my answer accordingly, cheers.

Comment: sure, edited question

Comment: @hedy, I have edited my solution now, kindly do check it once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: This looks great, though it seems the blah's on its own line aren't kept?

Comment: @hedy, Also change from `[^{}a-zA-Z]` to `[^{}a-zA-Z0-9]` in case of you need digits also between `{` and `}`.

Comment: I would've liked a sed solution but this looks awesome, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @hedy, your welcome, trust me even I love `sed` but `awk` is much much better and efficient programming than `sed`, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @hedy, I have also added a Generic solution, in case we have multiple occurrences of `{..}` then it will work with that also, cheers.

Answer (score 4):

With `sed` (tested on `GNU sed`, syntax may vary for other implementations):

```sh
$ sed -E ':a s/(\{[[:alnum:]]*)[^[:alnum:]]+([^}]*})/\1\2/; ta' ip.txt
x.y={aaabc} blah
blah
x.y={123def} blah
blah
```

- `:a` marks that location as label `a` (used to jump using `ta` as long as the substitution succeeds)
- `(\{[[:alnum:]]*)` matches `{` followed by zero or more alnum characaters
- `[^[:alnum:]]+` matches one or more non-alnum characters
- `([^}]*})` matches till the next `}` character

---

If `perl` is okay:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/\{\K[^}]+(?=\})/$&=~s|[^a-z\d]+||gir/e' ip.txt
x.y={aaabc} blah
blah
x.y={123def} blah
blah
```

- `\{\K[^}]+(?=\})` match sequence of `{` to `}` (assuming `}` cannot occur in between)

  - `\{\K` and `(?=\})` are used to avoid the braces from being part of the matched portion
- `e` flag allows you to use Perl code in replacement portion, in this case another substitute command
- `$&=~s|[^a-z\d]+||gir` here, `$&` refers to entire matched portion, `gi` flags are used for global/case-insensitive and `r` flag is used to return the value of this substitution instead of modifying `$&`

  - `[^a-z\d]+` matches non-alphanumeric characters (assuming ASCII, you can also use `[^[:alnum:]]+`)
  - use `\W+` if you want to preserve underscores as well

---

For both solutions, you can add `x\.y=` prefix if needed to narrow the scope of matching.

Comment: The sed solution looks amazing! I do think this should be the accepted answer, though I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the `a` marker and `ta` do? It seems like it doesn't keep looking for the alnum/non-alnum's if they were removed, so it looks a bit like a loop.

Comment: Yeah, it is a loop. The `t` command jumps to the given label only if the substitution succeeds. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands for more details.

Comment: Perhaps the sed solution could be: `sed -E ':a;s/(\{[[:alnum:]]*)[^}[:alnum:]]/\1/;ta' file`?

Comment: yeah, especially if adding `x\.y=` prefix would help to prevent false matches if `{` is present elsewhere in the input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `gnu-awk` solution using `FPAT`:

```sh
s='x.y={aaa b .c}'
awk -v OFS= -v FPAT='{[^}]+}|[^{}]+' '
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i ~ /^{/) $i = "{" gensub(/[^[:alnum:]]+/, "", "g", $i) "}"
} 1' <<< "$s"

x.y={aaabc}
```